# Order of solving a function.

Tags: functions

> What is the proper order to solve functions and their inverses? Is it different from working across the equal sign in an normal algebra problem, as in is there a special way just because its a function?

Here is the simple problem that seriously got me wondering: Given $f(x) = -2x + 4$, find $f^{-1}(x)$.

This is how I worked it:
$$
f(x) = y = -2x + 4\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
\frac{y}{-2} = \frac{-2x}{ -2} + 4\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
\frac{y}{-2} - 4= x + (4 -4)\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
\frac{y}{-2} -4= x = f^{-1}(x)
$$
This is how it was supposed to be solved:
$$
f(x) = y = -2x + 4\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
 y - 4= -2x + (4 - 4)\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
 \frac{y}{-2} + \frac{-4}{-2} = \frac{-2x}{-2}\\[0.5em]
\Downarrow\\[0.5em]
 \frac{y}{-2} + 2 = x = f^{-1}(x)
$$
As you can see I did my math right (or did I?) but I got the order wrong.  I've been solving Algebra and even Trig for years and I always passed with about a C+ I'm wondering if my order of doing things has been wrong all this time and I've just been lucky enough to pass? Any help would be appreciated as I am about to begin calculus in a couple of months.

Comment: There is an error in the first step.  On the right-hand side, the $4$ needs to be divided by $-2$ also.  It was not the order here that was of issue.  It was just an oversight.

Comment: Note that your order *requires* you to do two divisions - that's why the usual order (addition/subtraction first, in this situation) is advisable; it helps prevent oversights as it requires only a single subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$ y=f(x)=>f^{-1}(y)=x$

> Observe these steps

.

*you can change the variable y to t or m or any thing you want  ... Yes it may be x also ....*

**Now $y=-2x+4 is given function $**
Substract 4 first from both side`s

$y-4=-2x+4-4$

$=>y-4=-2x$

```
Next divide with -2 on both sides
```

$\frac{y-4}{-2}=\frac{-2x}{-2}$
$=>\frac{4-y}{2}=x$

But we have $x=f^{-1}(y)$
So 
$=>\frac{4-y}{2}=x=f^{-1}(y)$

Now change the variable y to x in $f^{-1}(y)$

Inverse function 
$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{4-x}{2}$